# Xcode XCUI swift tests failing while being debugged

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

In our app we have set up many automated tests using Apple's XCUI framework. However, in order to speed up the process that it took to run all of the UI tests, we integrated some(as little as possible) of our testing code into our app in order to bypass a 1-2 minute sync with our server. The problem is, whenever we try to use the debugger within our app during the

```
XCUIApplication().launch()
```

call, the test case will fail after about 20 seconds, stop the debugger, and respond with a test case failure message of

```
"failed with error: NotFound"
```

which obviously isn't very a helpful error message.

Is this a bug within XCUI testing that cannot be fixed, or is there some type of timeout within XCUIApplication().launch() that can be disabled?